# images aren't displayed locally

Tags: php, image, symfony

I'm doing the maintenance on a project developed with the symfony framework version 2.7. The problem I'm encountering is that the images aren't displayed locally but they are displayed in the online version.

The images are stored in web/uploads/Images. Following code is the one used to display the site's logo: `<img src="{{ asset(setting.logo) }}?{{"now"|date("d/m/Y H:i:s")}}" data-bs-hover-animate="swing" class="logo">`.

When I inspect local version with my browser, it displays: `<img src="/uploads/logo.png?30/12/2019 13:37:21" data-bs-hover-animate="swing" class="logo">` and the logo is not displayed.

But when I modify the source code in local : `<img src="{{ asset('uploads/Images/LogoALEX.png') }}?{{"now"|date("d/m/Y H:i:s")}}" data-bs-hover-animate="swing" class="logo">` the image is displayed.

Now I don't want to modify the source code since it works already online.please I'd like to have an explanation for this issue and know how to fix it.

Comment: Please provide the source code you are using currently

Comment: There's a problem with your asset configuration on the local machine, it doesn't specify the `Images` subdirectory.

Comment: have you tried it with uploads/logo.png too? do you have the logo.png file? has it the correct permissions?

Comment: Have you run webpack or gulp locally? This may be setup to copy the files from assets to the web directory

Comment: Bamar how can I modify the asset configuration? because I'm new on the symphony framework

Comment: Rufinus when I try: <img src="{{ asset('uploads/logo.png')}}> , the image is displayed correctly.and when I inspect the browser displays: <img src="/alexandrieUpdate/web/uploads/logo.png>.I don't understand why when I write <img src="{{ asset(setting.logo) }}> the image doesn't display and when I inspect the browser it displays <img src="/uploads/logo.png>.